# Can I use self-signed SSL certificate server to deploy Enterprise app over air?

Tags: ios, enterprise, software-distribution

After iOS 7.1 ，if we want to deploy our Enterprise app over air, the URL for the **manifest.plist** file has to be HTTPS.

For example:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist
```

In my server I use a self-signed SSL certificate. When I tap the URL on an iPhone, it says `Could not connect to <ip-address>` and logs the typical

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x15d37040 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be `<ip-address>`, which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

So, I want to know whether I can use the self-signed SSL certificate or not?

If I can, how do I resolve the problem the problem I've encountered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First have the user install the self-signed SSL certificate on their device. Or use a free verified SSL service.

You will need to have the user install this file https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file

I believe this service provides browser-validated SSL certificates. https://www.startssl.com/?app=1

Comment: I did install the certificate on their device,but it still not work.I will try the free ssl certificates, thank you .

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think iOS has a requirement for SSL certificates that they be signed by a root CA. Try making your own CA, and then installing the cert that the CA signs. Also, is your SSL for setup correctly. Did you set the server name parameter rite when creating it?